# Compare 2 values of the same row of a matrix with the row and column index of another matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix1 with 11217 rows and 2 columns, a second matrix2 which has 10 rows and 10 columns. Now, I want to compare the values in the rows of matrix 1 with the indices of matrix 2 and if these are the same then the value of the corresponding index (currently 0) of the matrix2 should be increased with +1.

```
     c1 <- x[2:11218] #these values go from 1 to 10
     #second column from index 3 to N
     c2 <- x[3:11219] #these values also go from 1 to 10
     #matrix with column c1 and c2
     m1 <- as.matrix(cbind(c1 = c1, c2 = c2))
     #empty matrix which will count the frequencies
     m2 <- matrix(0, nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
     #change row and column names of m2 to the numbers of 1 to 10
     dimnames(m2) <-list(c(1:10), c(1:10))
     #go through every row of the matrix m1 and look which rotation appears, add 1 to m2 if the rotation
     #equals the corresponding index
     r <- c(1:10)
     c <- c(1:10)
     for (i in 1:nrow(m1)) {
        if(m1[i,1] == r & m1[i,2] == c)
     m2[r,c]+1
     }
```

no frequencies where calculated, i don't understand why?

Comment: you might want to replace the last line with `m2[r,c] = m2[r,c] + 1`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are trying to replicate the behavior of `table`. I'd recommend just using it instead.

Simpler data (it appears you did not include variable `x`):

```
m1 <-
  matrix(round(runif(20, 1,10))
         , ncol = 2)
```

Then, use `table`. Here, I am setting the values of each column to be a factor to ensure that the right columns are generated:

```
table(factor(m1[,1], 1:10)
      , factor(m1[,2], 1:10))
```

gives:

```
      1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
  1   3  4  0  4  2  0  5  3  2  0
  2   3  7  9  7  4  5  3  4  5  2
  3   4  6  3 10  8  9  4  2  7  3
  4   5  2 14  3  7 13  8 11  3  3
  5   2 13  2  5  8  5  7  7  8  6
  6   1 10  7  4  5  6  8  5  8  5
  7   3  3  6  5  4  5  4  8  7  7
  8   5  5  8  7  6 10  5  4  3  4
  9   2  5  8  4  7  4  4  6  4  2
  10  3  1  2  3  3  5  3  5  1  0
```